# Socket.IO will not respond

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

On my server side, I can't get a listener attached to a client connection to respond.  I can successfully emit a message when a client connects, as well as successfully respond to the server from the client side, but can't respond beyond that.

## Server

```
// communication scheme
//
// (1) server responds to client connection with 'welcome'
// (2) client immediately responds with 'thanks'
// (3) server's User class SHOULD respond with 'np', however this
//     is never emitted


class User {
    constructor(socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.socket.on('thanks', function() {
            // !!! Point at which code doesn't work
            // the code inside here is never reached
            this.socket.emit('np');
        })
        this.socket.emit('welcome');
    }
}

class Server {
    constructor(port) {
        this.app = require('express')();
        this.server = require('http').Server(this.app);
        this.io = require('socket.io')(this.server);

        this.server.listen(port);
        this.io.on('connection', function(socket) {
            var user = new User(socket);
        });
    }
}
```

## Client

```
this.io.on('welcome', function() {
    this.io.emit('thanks', {});
});

this.io.on('np', function() {
    console.log("I never get here either");
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you have some errors in the console that would give you good clues as to what is going on.

Comment: @jfriend00 I actually had no errors at all

Comment: If the accepted answer is right and you were essentially doing `user.socket.socket.emit`, then there was an error somewhere that you should have been able to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do the value of `this` which changes in the body of the callback from the 'thanks' event. `this` no longer refers to the User object, it refers to the object which called the function which is `user.socket`. You are basically calling `user.socket.socket.emit` which doesn't exist. There is a trick around this, store the scope of this in another variable so we can access it later.

```js
class User {
    constructor(socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
        var that = this;
        this.socket.on('thanks', function() {
            // !!! Point at which code doesn't work
            // the code inside here is never reached
            that.socket.emit('np');
        })
        this.socket.emit('welcome');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it led me to the solution.  However, it should be noted that the that = this trick should also be used @ this.io.on('np'){...}

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to access User.socket but were actually accessing the User.socket.socket when trying to emit `'np'` from the server. I changed it to use an ES6 arrow function to fix the issue, if you want to read up on it some [arrow function this](http://es6-features.org/#Lexicalthis) should explain it pretty well.

```js
class User {
  constructor(socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.socket.on('thanks', () => {
      this.socket.emit('np');
    });
    this.socket.emit('welcome');
  }
}
```

Comment: Arrow functions work great around the problem, however, we can't use them client side yet. Poor browser support.

Comment: True, your answer is the better solution for client side code.